# Sum attributes from one table and add to another in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

In QGIS 3, I have two layers:

- Polygon layer representing properties including an attribute on the type of property: residential, commercial, industrial, open space etc.
- point layer representing connections to watermains

I have used the NNJoin plugin to determine the closest point for each of the properties, and this reference is now in the property layer.

For each point, I now want to sum the number of properties of each type and add this to point layer.

For example:

```
Point  Residential Commercial Industrial etc
 1        3           0           4
 2        7           2           5
 ...
 5000     5           5           15
```

I was going to export it to Excel to undertake a series of "Sum Ifs", but didn't want to take it out of GIS unless I had to.

Is there a method to achieve this in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your point layer has 1 attribute: 'point_id' 
and your polygon layer has 3 attributes: 'pgon_id', 'type' and 'closest_point'

1. Run the toolbox 'Join attributes by field value' with the inputs set as the screenshot below.

[image]

2. Open field calculator on your new joined layer and create a new field "Residential" of type integer with the expression `count(  "type" , "point_id" , "type" = 'residential' )`.
3. Repeat step 2 for each type of property (industrial etc...) and save edits.
4. Run the toolbox 'Delete duplicates by attribute' with the new joined layer as the input layer and point_id set as the field to match duplicates by.
5. Delete the fields 'pgon_id', 'type' and 'closest_point' from the new layer. You will be left with an attribute table like the one below.

[image]